# Application class does not run when app start?

Tags: android

I am using Application class but it's not running when App start
here is my code:

```
public class App extends Application {
//
private static final String TAG = App.class.getSimpleName();
public static SharedPreferences sPrefs;
private static App sInstance;

public static App getsInstance() {
    return sInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    }
    Log.e(TAG,"onCreate()");
    sInstance = this;
    sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}
//some methods
}
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

when I put a breakpoint inside onCreate() and run a debug it doesn't stop on it
any help?

Comment: but do you see the Log?

Comment: No,I did not...

Comment: Application doesn't run. You need an activity if you are trying to display stuff to the user. You could try setting the application class as the launcher, but I doubt it would work.

Comment: The application have activities ofcourse

Comment: I figured out that the app class doesn't run when I used App.sPrefs in some activity and get NullPointerException.

Comment: This is not a good way of building singleton. Do not use the Application class for this instead create a new class and put your singleton logic.

Comment: It works when I disabled instant run, I think IDE need to be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to uninstall app , clean project and install it again.

Comment: Can you please provide package name of your App class?

Comment: It works when I disabled instant run, I think IDE need to be updated